# PostgreSQL Lateral join when right table row doesn't exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, postgresql-9.6, lateral-join

When I have in my DB a category without posts, the resulted select returns rows without an empty category. How to do receiving a table with empty category.

```
  SELECT
    c.id as category_id,
    pp.id as post_id
  FROM categories c,
  LATERAL
  (SELECT
    id
  FROM posts
  WHERE c.id = posts.category_id
   ORDER BY views DESC
   LIMIT 2) pp
  ORDER BY c.category ASC, pp.id ASC
```

Current query result:

```
category_id | post_id
----------------------
1           | 1
1           | 2
3           | 3
3           | 4
```

I need:

```
category_id | post_id
----------------------
1           | 1
1           | 2
2           |
3           | 3
3           | 4
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `left join`:

```
SELECT
    c.id as category_id,
    pp.id as post_id
FROM categories c
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
(SELECT
    id
FROM posts
WHERE c.id = posts.category_id
    ORDER BY views DESC
    LIMIT 2) pp ON TRUE
ORDER BY c.category ASC, pp.id ASC
```

Notice I have used `on true` as the joining condition since the lateral join references previous table.

Comment: Thank you! While you're writing I've found a working `LEFT JOIN`, but I missed `on true`. Thank you for the notice very much!

Comment: @UliankaShu no problem, consider upvoting & accepting the answer